# Is it possible to suggest an IP to my DHCP server for my client to use?

Tags: dns, dhcp

Is it possible for a DHCP client on Linux to suggest an IP to a DHCP server? I have no access to the DHCP server.

I cannot use static networking, or DNS will not work. (DNS on my network is set up via DHCP via DHCP_HOSTNAME entry, and that *alone*)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The DHCP server issues IPs to clients requesting one.

If you had access to the DHCP server, you could fix the IP in the DHCP server config by binding it to the MAC address of your card.